# Drawing a pie chart

Tags: python, pie-chart

I've recently been given a task to draw a pie chart only using the `import` functions of `import turle`. I have the chart title, segment labels and percentages that are needed yet I am not sure exactly on drawing this up.

What would be the easier, neatest procedure to do this?

I was thinking of drawing the segments first and then adding labels. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us what you've got.

Comment: I honestly have nothing yet... I dont know how to even start it... Ive been searching for about an hour for tutorials on how to do it but everyone is importing a certain function ect...

Comment: Start by drawing a circle with turtle. Next try drawing a wedge. Now draw two adjacent wedges. Can you make a wedge with a variable angle? Try to build up a solution from pieces that you understand.

Comment: Cheers man, I have started with the circle but I was thinking if I put each wedge into a definition and store the percentages as a list if that would work?

Comment: @floppy12 Im really new to this.. How would I do that exactly? So far I am working on making a definition so it will take the percentage from the list and do each wedge on its own without repetitive coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
You should do it step by step :
- Circle
- Then for each segments
go to center
trace radius (you should compute the coordinates of points on circle with simple polar algebra)
add color
add label
```

Yes storing percentages/labels as a list seems to be a good thing.

Edit : 
If your percentages are in list you can iterate with syntax
for perc in list

Then you can compute the angle theta by multiplying 2pi * percentage

To trace radius [OM], you need the cartesian coordinates of M(r, theta) which are (rcos(theta) ; rsin(theta) )

Comment: Im really new to this.. How would I do that exactly? So far I am working on making a definition so it will take the percentage from the list and do each wedge on its own without repetitive coding.